# Getting error on production server with outlook email rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp-auth

I have setup outlook email for sending emails in my rails application,

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.office365.com',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication       => :login,
    :user_name      => ENV['username'],
    :password       => ENV['password'],
    :domain         => "office.com",
}
```

Getting error on productionn server, settings are working fine on development enviornment

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.office365.com" does not match
>   the server certificate

Comment: set  `openssl_verify_mode: none`  in smtp_settings

Comment: Now i got this: ::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535 Incorrect authentication data

Comment: may be your user name and password are incorrect. did you set user name and password in enviroment variables ?

Comment: Yes they are working fine in development envoirnmnt

Comment: Did you set environment variables on production ? which gem you are using for set environment variables ?

Comment: Instead of environment i just changed to original username and password, still getting error SMTPAuthenticationError: 535

Comment: You mean you set the original user name and password directly in smtp config ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166530/discussion-between-zia-qamar-and-vishal).

Comment: Did you check chat ?